# deferred services and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred, angularjs-service

I'm trying to create app with deferred services - service need to perform async operation before it can be usable by controllers.

according to docs i should load any deferred data inside object passed to when() function:

> `resolve - {Object.<string, function>=} -` An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, **the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated**.

but i can't force it to work.

app:

```js
...
var loaded = false;
var deferData = {
  dfr: ['$rootScope', 'service', function($rootScope, service) {
      if (!loaded) {
        loaded = true;
        return service.loadData();
      }
    }
  ]
};
...
$routeProvider.when('/main', {
  templateUrl: './main.html',
  controller: 'mainCtrl',
  resolve: deferData
});

// default
$routeProvider.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/main',
  resolve: deferData
});
...
```

service:

```js
app.factory('service', ['$q',

function($q) {
  var s = {
    loadData: function() {
      var d = $q.defer();
      console.log('starting defer');
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('defer resolve');
        d.resolve('timeout');
      }, 2500);
      return d.promise;
    }
  };
  return s;
}
```

]);

this code sholud output (run, load defers, instantiate controller):

```js
app run
starting defer
defer resolve
controller  init
```

but it output:

```js
app run
starting defer
controller  init
defer resolve
```

link to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k2D2taxAhSJkt5O174aw?p=preview

what i'm doing wrong? maybe i should resolve all my defers in `.run(function(){ ... })`? how to force router to wait until all defers resolved?

P.S. in my project i've got several services. some of them stores their settings in async storage, some of them need to be initialized after couple of http queries. i'm trying to prepare all my services with `$q.all([ srv1.load(), srv2.load(), ... ])` and pass that final promise to `resolove` in router configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> resolve - {Object.=} - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

Therefore, to use `resolve` correctly, you should something like the following in your `MainCtrl`:

```
function MainCtrl(..., deferData) {
    ...
}
```

And the route should be:

```
$routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: './main.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    resolve: {
        deferData: deferData
    }
});
```

### Update:

The problem is you have **two** `resolve`s in your `$routeProvider` call. Once you remove the one in the default route, your code should work as expect.

Comment: but if i use `['$scope', '$routeParams', 'delay', function($scope, $routeParams, delay)` in controller and

   `var deferData = { delay: ['$rootScope', 'service', function($rootScope, service) {  ...  }  ]  };`

in route config `{ ... resolve: deferData, ... }`,  i still got wrong output, can't get it to work properly

Comment: @StasTitenko I have found the problem, and it's because you have *two* `resolve`s in `$routeProvider`!

Comment: @StasTitenko I have updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: ty, it works. even with multiple `resolve` in `$routeProvider`, just without one for `default` (       `$routeProvider.when('/secondary', { ...  resolve: deferData }); $routeProvider.when('/main', { ... resolve: deferData });`).

**BUT**, if while defer resolving for first controller we click on link to second, it will output `secondary controller  init`, no matter single or multiple declaration of `resolve` we have. Can we somehow fix that, and prevent controller fire before we prepare services for app? Also how can we use same async prepared services in directives?

Comment: @StasTitenko The global `loaded` flag is the problem, after you resolved the data for the first time, `service.loadData()` won't be called anymore. But that is a different question, you should create a new question for your further concerns.